# ValueError: Expected input batch_size (784) to match target batch_size (2)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm beginner in pytorch, here is my simple code to doing a simple train and eval on image dataset : my batch_size = 2

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2048,2048)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2048, 3)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.model.conv1(x))
        print('model_shape:',x.shape)
        x = x.view(-1,2048*1*1)
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))     
        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc2(x), dim=1)
        return x
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])
model = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for epoch in range(100):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = data
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 99:
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 100))
     with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            inputs, labels = data
            outputs = model(inputs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    print('Accuracy of the network on the test set: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))
```

Error was: `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (784) to match target batch_size (2).`

I'm trying to figure out what the problem is, knowing that i outputs model_shape: `torch.Size([2, 64, 112, 112])`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue comes from your line `x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))`. This is because of the view right before this line: before the view `x` is of the shape you gave ([2, 64, 112, 112]) but after the view, it becomes of shape [784, 2048], so you are losing your batch dimension.

If you want to keep the batch dimension to 2, you could change your view to `x.view(2, -1, 2048*1*1)`.